# find duplicate values in each line

Tags: awk, grep

How can I print lines which have duplicate (x2) values ?

E.g

```
01 02 03
01 01 03
01 01 01 03
```

out of these three lines, only line two is correct.

so now let's say I want to look up for line where the value occurred x3.

in this case line 3 is correct.

Comment: When you’re looking for duplicates, does it matter which value is duplicated? For example, would `01 03 03` be valid? What about `01 01 03 03`?

Comment: thank you for your response. No it does not matter which value is selected. And yes 01 03 03 is valid, and even 01 01 03 03.

Comment: @αғsнιη exactly with duplicate, it means x2. for 01 01 01 03, 01 occurs x3. The first answer is by way the easiest approach. And the 3rd answer is a great way to print more info about the results. Haven't tried the 2nd method yet. Thanks a lot for all the help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk

```
awk -v nb=3 '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(++a[$i]>nb){print;next}}' infile
```

---

> for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)  on each field of the line
>   ++a[$i] get each field in a associative array a and incremente it each time we saw a field with the same value.
>   if(++a[$i]>nb) if the value is more than nb
>   {print;next} print the line and jump to the next line

---

To show only the line with `nb`

```
awk -v nb=3 '
{
    max = 0
    delete a
    for ( i=1 ; i<=NF ; i++ )
        ++a[$i]
    for( j in a )
        max = a[j]>max ? a[j] : max
    if ( max == nb )
        print
}' infile
```

Comment: Been playing around with the coeff.  Thank you it does work. Very clear explanation.

Comment: when i use nb=1, i get all the double even the triple ones, because of the (++a[$i]>nb), which implies that all doubles , triples or anythign higher is correct. But is there a way to limit it to only nb=1. Been trying to modify (++a[$i]>nb), but its not working.

Comment: Update the answer to limit

Comment: See also `split("", a)` for a standard/portable equivalent of `delete a`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for tip, only man mawk give mawk supports an extension, delete array. Another way is to define a function getmax() with the array local.

Comment: @ctac_ when i use the `awk -F [^A-z] - v nb=3` to selected letters which are duplicated, all lines containing both letters and numbers are skipped. Is there a method to prevent this exclusion.

Comment: Try echo '01 02 03' | awk -F [^A-z] '{print NF}' print 9. Each char is a field separator (not in A-z) . So there is 9 empty fields.

Comment: @ctac_ Thank you for the clarification about the echo and the empty fields.

Answer (score 0):

With AWK:

```
awk -v t=2 '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) c[$i]++; for (v in c) if (c[v] == t) {print; next}}'
```

This processes each line, and within each line, counts the occurrences of each value (each field) in the associative array `c`; then it goes over all the values `v` it has seen, and if one of the values was seen the required number of times (as specified by the target, `t`), it prints the line, and skips to the next line to avoid printing the line multiple times (*e.g.* for `01 01 03 03`).

Comment: You'd need to empty the array (like with `split("", c)` or `delete c` with some implementations) between each record.

Answer (score 0):

This will only print lines with duplicate space-delimited words:

```
while IFS='' read -r line ; do  if [[ "`echo $line | tr ' ' '\n'| sort | uniq -d`" != '' ]]; then echo "$line"; fi; done < YOURFILE
```

For your example the output will be:

> 01 01 03
>
> 01 01 01 03

Here, for the more than one occurrence of "01" in lines 2 and 3...

If you want to specify number of times a word should be checked to be repeated then :

```
NO=3; lnr=1 ; while IFS='' read -r line ; do echo "for line" $lnr ; echo $line | tr ' ' '\n' | uniq -c| grep -e "^\s*$NO" ; ((lnr++)); done < YOURFILE
```

For your example output will be:

> for line 1
>
> for line 2
>
> for line 3
>
> ```
>  3 01
> ```

The first number is the number of times you specified in variable `NO` for the number of occurrences to check. 
The second number is the actual word that was found out to be repeating NO times. 
Change YOURFILE to your file, of course.